# setOnClickListener Error in Android Studio

Tags: android, kotlin

I get this error, when i try to run my kotlin activity:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ImageView.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference
        at com.example.b1.activity.RegisterActivity.onCreate(RegisterActivity.kt:29)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8146)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8130)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1310)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3660)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3858) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:140) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:100) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2288) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:254) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8190) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:612) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1006)
```

I try to delete some of my code to find what caused this error, and i find that:

```
back_button.setOnClickListener{
            val intent = Intent(this@RegisterActivity, LoginActivity::class.java)
            intent.flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK or Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK
            startActivity(intent)
       }
```

This back_button click give me the trouble. The problem is, this code already been in my project for awhile and never cause any problem till today. Anyone know why this happen?

My full code at bellow:

```
package com.example.b1.activity

import android.content.Intent
import android.graphics.Color
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.text.*
import android.text.method.LinkMovementMethod
import android.text.style.ClickableSpan
import android.util.Patterns
import android.view.View
import android.widget.Toast
import com.example.b1.R
import com.example.b1.firestore.FirestoreClass
import com.example.b1.model.User
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.action_bar.*
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.daftar.*
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.masuk.*


class RegisterActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.daftar)

        
        back_button.setOnClickListener{
            val intent = Intent(this@RegisterActivity, LoginActivity::class.java)
            intent.flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK or Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK
            startActivity(intent)
       }
        button_login_sekarang.setOnClickListener {
           startActivity(Intent( this@RegisterActivity, LoginActivity::class.java))
           finish()
        }
        buatAkun.setOnClickListener {
            when
            {
                !syaratketentuan.isChecked->{
                    Toast.makeText(
                        this@RegisterActivity,
                        "Harap Menyetujui Syarat dan Ketentuan",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show()
                }
                TextUtils.isEmpty(tvUsername.text.toString().trim{it<= ' ' })->{
                    Toast.makeText(
                        this@RegisterActivity,
                        "Isi Username",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show()
                }
                TextUtils.isEmpty(tvAlamatemail.text.toString().trim{it<= ' ' })->{
                    Toast.makeText(
                        this@RegisterActivity,
                        "Isi Email",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show()
                }
               !Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(tvAlamatemail.getText().toString()).matches()->{
                   Toast.makeText(
                       this@RegisterActivity,
                       "Invalid Email",
                       Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                       .show()
               }
                TextUtils.isEmpty(tvNomorseluler.text.toString().trim{it<= ' ' })->{
                    Toast.makeText(
                        this@RegisterActivity,
                        "Isi Nomor Seluler",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show()
                }
                TextUtils.isEmpty(Password.text.toString().trim{it<= ' ' })->{
                    Toast.makeText(
                        this@RegisterActivity,
                        "Isi Nomor Seluler",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show()
                }
                else ->{
                    val username: String =tvUsername.text.toString().trim{it<= ' '}
                    val email: String =tvAlamatemail.text.toString().trim{it<= ' '}
                    val nomorSeluler: String =tvNomorseluler.text.toString().trim{it<= ' '}
                    val password: String =Password.text.toString().trim{it<= ' '}

                    if(syaratketentuan.isChecked){
                        FirebaseAuth.getInstance().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email,password).addOnCompleteListener(
                            {task ->
                                if(task.isSuccessful){
                                    val firebaseUser: FirebaseUser = task.result!!.user!!

                                    Toast.makeText(
                                        this@RegisterActivity,
                                        "Berhasil Mendaftar",
                                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                                    ).show()

                                    val intent = Intent(this@RegisterActivity, LoginActivity::class.java)
                                    intent.flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK or Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK
                                    intent.putExtra("user_id", firebaseUser.uid)
                                    intent.putExtra("email_id", email)
                                    startActivity(intent)
                                    finish()
                                }else{
                                    Toast.makeText(
                                        this@RegisterActivity,
                                        "Berhasil Mendaftar",
                                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                                    ).show()
                                }
                            }
                        )
                    }

                }
            }


        }

        val text ="Saya menyetujui syarat dan ketentuan aplikasi ini"
        val spanString= SpannableString(text)
        val clickableSpan=object : ClickableSpan()
        {
            override fun onClick(widget: View) {
                Toast.makeText(this@RegisterActivity, "Belum makai syarat",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

            }

            override fun updateDrawState(ds: TextPaint) {
                super.updateDrawState(ds)
                ds.color=Color.RED
            }
        }
        spanString.setSpan(clickableSpan,16,36,Spannable.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE)
        skText.text=spanString
        skText.movementMethod=LinkMovementMethod.getInstance()
    }
}
```

Comment: did you use kotlin extensions?

Comment: make sure you have back_button in R.layout.daftar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to initialize `back_button` before you attach anything to it

```
back_button = findViewById(R.id.back_button);
back_button.setOnClickListener{ ... rest of code
```

you have to get reference to every `View` you want to set up by code further, so also `button_login_sekarang` and `buatAkun`

alsoe ensure that all these `View`s are placed inside set layout (`R.layout.daftar`)

Comment: he seems to be using kotlin synthetic properties, In that case you can refer views simply using ids. since findViewById stuff is done under the hood

Comment: well, this must be somehow enabled with some flag, thats not default behaviour for shure... (not in my Kotlin projects)

Comment: There is a gradle plugin(now deprecated) which you can add to your project and then you can access views directly

Comment: consider upvoting/accepting answer if helpful, good luck!

Answer (score 1):

For kotlin synthetic imports, you should import the layout like this

```
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.daftar.*
```

given you called

```
setContentView(R.layout.daftar)
```

remove the other synthetic imports.

Answer (score 0):

Your imports:

```
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.action_bar.*
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.daftar.*
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.masuk.*
```

As you are importing several `synthetics` and get null pointer exception, it seems you have several views with `back_button` id in your project. You should only call views from `main.daftar` in this Activity as you set `R.layout.daftar` to this activity.

P.s: If you want to avoid this kind of disadvantage of `synthetic` you can replace it with [view binding](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding) which is recommended to use instead of `kotlin synthetic`

Answer (score 0):

check the `.xml` file of register `Activity` and add Kotlin Extensions in `build.gradle` file.

If it didn't work then add

android:onClick="backButton"

to button's `xml`

and create a `fun`:

```
fun backButton(){
}
```

and write the `setonClicklistener` code in it.